# JavaScript add a line break after every 12th character in a string which has HTML tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have a string which is a combination of many small strings, wrapped around a HTML tag.
The target is to add a line break after every 12th character excluding the tags.

```
'<span>This is a text.</span><span>Lets go for the walk now.</span>'

'<span>This is a te\nxt.</span><span>Lets go f\nor the walk\n now.</span>'
```

What I have tried is to ignore the  and get the value in between the tags.

```
    let messageString = '<span>This is a text.</span><span>Lets go for the walk now.</span>';
    messageString.match(/(?<=<span>).*?(?=<\/span>)/g).forEach((s) => {
        messageString = messageString.replace(s, s.replace(/.{12}/g, '$&\n'));
  });
```

But I get wrong output from this. I understand that I am picking here the text in between the tags, so the count to 12 is not working. so should I have a counter or something to loop through till the count 12 is reached and then add a line break. Just thinking if there is a more simple way to do this.

Comment: Hi ! Please show us a code sample of what you tried so we can help better

Comment: not sure it will feet to your case, but there is a tag <br> https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_br

Comment: Note that in your example desired output, the third `"\n"` character occurs after 11 characters, not 12 — it should follow the `" "` instead of the `"k"`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to walk the node tree, and iterate every code point of text content as you encounter text nodes along the way, inserting a newline every time the count reaches 12. Here's a functional example:

```js
function insertStringEveryNCodePoints (node, frequency, str) {
  const stack = [node];
  let count = 0;

  while (stack.length > 0) {
    const node = stack.shift();

    if (node.nodeType !== Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      for (const n of node.childNodes) stack.push(n);
      continue;
    }

    let text = '';

    for (const s of node.textContent) {
      count += 1;
      text += s;

      if (count === frequency) {
        text += str;
        count = 0;
      }
    }

    node.textContent = text;
  }
}

// Your input string:
const html = `<span>This is a text.</span><span>Lets go for the walk now.</span>`;

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');

console.log(JSON.stringify(doc.body.innerHTML)); // "<span>This is a text.</span><span>Lets go for the walk now.</span>"

insertStringEveryNCodePoints(doc.body, 12, '\n');

console.log(JSON.stringify(doc.body.innerHTML)); // "<span>This is a te\nxt.</span><span>Lets go f\nor the walk \nnow.</span>"
```

[Code in the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDMBnApgJygZSplAcwFEA3LATwDkBhOAE3QAU4UpVEAKAKEUTAboAXIiqCANL0TBM6AI4h0kCiLAgAtgCMskvqnwj9BMIUkBKEaVb1EAbykQE+xPoCGEANYixjANoBdRABeRF8BRn8AbikAG3QoREdwBJCABmipAHcACxg4rjdPADo4kyhsxAA+RFSzOyk+RzQE8PRglyh3DyLUXOAoTjMAQgy+PhhgLlai1oAVCgAHNqGgkJ90ItniAA1ZgH0qAHkAEWI6+zGx4DhMLibnJDhJ6YhcmPp11DrC7oWQXs4YDM0UujQQsDU6BBYwAvtwGog4gkoOgAB4pRAAckxoyuNzuTgSHCe-EERRR6LoYBR1KG5wRYOSiAA1CEAIzQy4UhKsly4y4TAlM1YhGTyRTKemgsbclkhIyc0FJantdIMxBwy5whHTblUmkY7nQuHagD0psQAE04CBbig-kT8EQhNx7glslB1DF2gADAA8qAWrjAlVmuQ4MA4rkQ3KKftNgeDlQDQZDABl4hxCHBpPjym1Mq4Yh5SZk4wnU5UfRk3Ygg5gMLcQmB0JlEMdDgBZJiuBtYQbRWv0OAQdr1xtFcfoABimDg6jwxkInA9XvEWO5ptXMUxwPh9zgcRKcGXACkcIcqD0nSYJhROMOIEVNAwKEUUC3MAAJWadtNmYFEHNRAACIUyTMNI2QKMYzRKBy0TENwPTTNEGzXNbnzRBC2LUsEMrED4RQRtcBvEhyEwag6EYFg2FQB8R2fV91zZAAmddMQAHTAXcaycQ8NhiE9OHPS9ryXO8GKfF96DfD8sB-P8AMiICLTAxDQ3DaDEGjFFuPRfCk2QyoM3YNCc2Abi82yAsixLbiBDLeMNMIoA)

Also note — as [@drent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8789415/drent) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74532585/javascript-add-a-line-break-after-every-12th-character-in-a-string-which-has-htm/74542826#comment131567589_74532585) — that this does not insert visual line breaks into your HTML. For that, you'll need a [line break element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br).